# Active Directory for remote location without dns -> lmhosts? hosts?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-10, hosts

I have a Domain Controller on main site which also is server for DNS.

At a remote site the router is not able to get DNS address via dhcp.

Is it possible to tell the Windows 10 client at the remote site (vpn) per `lmhosts` / `hosts` file how to resolve the pdc-name to ip?

Like last answer here: [Windows domain authentication using HOST files](https://serverfault.com/questions/246795/windows-domain-authentication-using-host-files)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure DNS servers (and additional DNS related settings) via group policy.  You can find it in `Computer Configuration - Administrative Templates - Network - DNS Client - DNS Servers`.

There's obviously a bit of a catch-22 here when new machines are spun up that don't necessarily have group policy applied yet. But however you were planning on populating a hosts file, why not just manually set the DNS servers at that point?

Comment: Thank you! So you think i should set up the DNS from the DC at the network interface of the windows 10-PC? Problem is 

- that this is a notebook and dhcp should be used in other networks and
- that all dns-querys will be forwarded to the main site.

What should i do?

What is the difference between setting the dns-server in group policy and setting it up in network config?

Thank you.

Comment: What you *should* do is fix your DHCP problem so that clients can get all of their settings properly.  Barring that for a mobile domain joined workstation, I'd probably just stick with manually changing DNS settings on the interface when necessary. Hosts files and group policy are a more permanent solution where the network isn't expected to change regularly.